# How to load files recursively using apache pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am pretty new to Pig and I have a a very basic question : can I make make Pig load all files from a directory including the ones in the subfolders ?
Here is how I proceed :

```
records = LOAD '/worldwide/data/' USING PigStorage() AS (event:chararray, user:chararray);
```

Here, `repo/data` may have subfolders such as

```
repo/data/region/cluster1
repo/data/region/cluster2
```

Can I get it to load everything from both those subdirectories and any new directories that might get added at a future date?

Comment: confirmed that the above statement just works and loads all of the data from the subdirectories into the records variable.

Answer (score 2):

confirmed that the above statement just works and loads all of the data from the subdirectories into the records variable.